# Trying to use ModalService. Getting "ModalService is undefined" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have loaded jquery, bootstrap, angularjs and modalservice in the right order. I am getting the error: "ModalService is undefined". Even though the ModalService has loaded properly. Can someone please help me to understand what is wrong:

```js
app.js:
var myApp=angular.module('App',['ngRoute','listApp']);
myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'list.html',
        controller: 'listCtrl'
    })
 .otherwise({
        templateUrl: 'list.html',
        controller: 'listCtrl'
    });
});

controllers.js:
var listApp=angular.module('listApp',['angularModalService']);
listApp.controller('listCtrl', ['$scope', function(scope,ModalService){
scope.show = function() {
ModalService.showModal({
 templateUrl: 'modal.html',
 controller: "ModalController"
}).then(function(modal) {
 modal.element.modal();
 modal.close.then(function(result) {
  scope.message = "You said " + result;
 });
});
};
}]);
listApp.controller('ModalController', function(scope, close) {
scope.close = function(result) {
close(result, 500); 
};
});
```

```html
index.html:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-routing.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-modal-service.js"></script>

list.html:
<div ng-app="listApp" ng-controller="listCtrl">
<a class="btn btn-default" href ng-click="show()">Show a Modal</a>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="modal.html">
 <div class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
 <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="close('Cancel')" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
  <h4 class="modal-title">Yes or No?</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
  <p>It's your call...</p>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" ng-click="close('No')" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
  <button type="button" ng-click="close('Yes')" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button>
   </div>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you create two angularjs modules? Remove the listApp and use myApp for the controller aswell as for the route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inject Your Dependency properly.

In your Controller added "ModalService" Dependency.

```
listApp.controller('listCtrl', ["$scope", "ModalService", function(scope, ModalService){
}]);
```

**Note:**

I highly recommend to use angular ui-bootstrap for modal service instead of separate plugin. It Provide a lot of handy options parameter to configure modal according to your requirement.

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

Hope This Helps!

Comment: Thanks, that is resolved. Also I am now using ui-bootstrap. Getting another error:  Unknown provider: scopeProvider <- scope <- ModalController. Any idea?

Comment: I got it. Thank you! I forgot the $ in ModalController!